# How to change + to - when parent menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change + to - when menu parent menu item is clicked. i was looking to target ::after element using jquery but i cant find way to target pseudo element using jquery

I want to change below css to when perent menu is clicked

```
.ir-nav-w > ul li::after {
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    content: "-";
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle code](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/ExaWxmm)

```js
$(".nav-w > ul > li > a").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


//open active list
$('.nav-w ul li').children().has('.active-menu').css('display', 'block');


// compare url with nav url to show active url 
$(function() {
  //var url = window.location.href;
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(
    window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
  );
  $(".nav-w ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == url || $(this).attr("href") == "") {
      $(this).addClass("active-menu");
    }
  });

  console.log("url : " + window.location.pathname);
});
```

```css
.nav-w a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* color: #178B43 !important; */
  color: #757575;
}


/* ul inside content area*/

.nav-w ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-w ul li {
  /*padding-left: 10px;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* ol inside content area*/

.nav-w>ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav-w ul>li ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.active-menu {
  color: red !important;
}

.nav-w>ul li::after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-w>ul li ul li::after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-w ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.nav-w a:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-left: 2px solid #178B43;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-w">

  <ul class="">
    <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Share Information</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-overview/">Share Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-graph/">Share Graph </a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/investor-calculator/">Investement Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-prices/">Historical Share Prices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Financial Information</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/earning-releases/">Earning Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/financial-statements/">Financial Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/presentation">Presentation
</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/quarterly-key-figures">Quarterly Key Figures
</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/annual-key-figures">Annual Key Figures
</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: psuedo content cant change with jquery, but you can add / remove the class based on click / slide toggle and display + / - with class .

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to add a class to the parent menu after it is clicked, such as `open`.

And then in your css you could add a special modifier:

```css
.nav-w > ul li.open::after {
    content: "-"
}
```

And when it is click again, remove the class `open`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't manipulate :after, because it's not technically part of the DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript. But you can add a new class with a new ::after specified.

Add this to your code:

```
// JS
const $listItems = $('.ir-nav-w > ul li');
$listItems.onClick(
  $listItems.removeClass('closed');
  this.addClass('closed')
);

// CSS
.ir-nav-w > ul li.closed::after {
  content: "+";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trick is to add css:

```css
.nav-w > ul li.selected::after {
    content: "-";
}
```

and toggle selected class on click:

```js
$(".nav-w > ul > li > a").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```js
$(".nav-w > ul > li > a").click(function () {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


//open active list
$('.nav-w ul li').children().has('.active-menu').css('display', 'block');
```

```css
.nav-w a {
 color: black;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 600;
 /* color: #178B43 !important; */
 color: #757575;

}
/* ul inside content area*/
.nav-w ul{
    margin-left: 0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:0px;

}
.nav-w ul li{
    /*padding-left: 10px;*/
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
/* ol inside content area*/
.nav-w > ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.nav-w  ul > li ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display:none;
}


.active-menu {
 color: red !important;
}
.nav-w > ul li::after {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 content: "+";
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px;
 top: 4px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
 z-index: 0;
}
.nav-w > ul li.selected::after {
   content: "-";
}
.nav-w > ul li ul li::after {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 5px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-size: 20px;
 z-index: 0;
}
.nav-w ul li ul li a {
    padding-left:45px;
}
.nav-w a:hover {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 border-left: 2px solid #178B43;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-w">

    <ul class="">
        <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Share Information</a>
            <ul class="" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-overview/">Share Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-graph/">Share Graph </a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/investor-calculator/" >Investement Calculator</a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-prices/">Historical Share Prices</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Financial Information</a>
            <ul class="" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/earning-releases/">Earning Releases</a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/financial-statements/">Financial Statements</a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/presentation">Presentation
</a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/quarterly-key-figures">Quarterly Key Figures
</a></li>
                <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/annual-key-figures">Annual Key Figures
</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how can we keep this as - if child menu is active & has  `active-menu` class <a href="/en/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-graph/" class="active-menu">Share Graph </a>`

Comment: There is currently no 'parent' selector in css and we need to mark it somehow from JS (here we toggle `selected` class). We should do that where we collapse/uncollapse our menu as shown in snipped (we could even uncolapse it automatically based on this class but this is different task to be honest, and deserves its own question).

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually possible to target `:after`, because it isn't part of the DOM and can't be accessed through JavaScript code. This isn't a jQuery limitation.

You could just set a class on the element itself, and change the `:after` rule when the class is set, i.e.:

```
.nav-w > ul li.active::after 
{
  content: "-"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add active class to the anchors' parent:

```
$(".nav-w > ul > li a").click(function () {
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

And replace ::after on the active class:

```
.nav-w > ul li.active::after {
   content: '-'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with :after prop.

You can do something like this

```
.li-item::after{
     content: "+";
}
.li-item-minus::after{
     content: "-" !important;
}
```

While in jQuery - you can toggle class `.li-item-minus` on click of each list item

```
jQuery(".naw-v ul li").on("click", function(){
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("li-item-minus");
});
```

Which means - on click of this li element, you toggleClass `li-item-minus` which has different content form main one.